# Retornar resultados com POST Jquery e PHP

Tags: jquery

Tenho este script que faz a busca no banco de dados e retorna os valores dentro de cada input:

```js
    $('#cidade_estado_sel').hide();
    
    function limpa_formulários(){
     $('#nome').val(""); 
     $('#telefone').val("");
     $('#celular').val(""); 
     $('#nome_empresa').val(""); 
     $('#descricao_resumida').val(""); 
     $('#princ_clientes_1').val("");
     $('#princ_clientes_2').val("");
     $('#princ_clientes_3').val(""); 

     $("#estado_sel").val("");
     $('#cidade_sel').val("");        
     $('#cidade_estado_no_sel').show();
     $('#cidade_estado_sel').hide();
    }
    
    $('#email').on('blur',function(){
     var user_email = $('#email').val();
     
     if(user_email == ""){
      limpa_formulários();
     }
     
     $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'php/getData.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data:{user_email:user_email},
      success:function(data){
       if(data.status == 'ok'){
        limpa_formulários();
        
        $('#nome').val(data.result.nome); 
        $('#telefone').val(data.result.telefone);
        $('#celular').val(data.result.celular); 
        $('#nome_empresa').val(data.result.nome_empresa); 
        $('#descricao_resumida').val(data.result.descricao_resumida); 
        $('#princ_clientes_1').val(data.result.princ_clientes_1);
        $('#princ_clientes_2').val(data.result.princ_clientes_2);
        $('#princ_clientes_3').val(data.result.princ_clientes_3);
        
        $('#cidade_estado_no_sel').hide();
        $('#cidade_estado_sel').show();
        $("#estado_sel").val(data.result.estado);
        $('#cidade_sel').val(data.result.cidade);

        alert(data.result.princ_clientes);        
       }else{
        limpa_formulários();
       }
      }
     });
    });
```

```html
<?php
 if(!empty($_POST['user_email'])){
  $data = array();
  
  /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/   
  include "../../Conexao/config.php";
      
  mysqli_select_db($config, $database_config);
  mysqli_set_charset($config,"utf8");
  /******* Conexão com o bando de dados *******/  
  
  //database details
  $dbHost     = $hostname_config;
  $dbUsername = $username_config;
  $dbPassword = $password_config;
  $dbName     = $database_config;
  
  //create connection and select DB
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  if($db->connect_error){
   die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
  }
  
  //get user data from the database 
  $query = $db->query("SELECT nome, telefone, celular, estado, cidade, nome_empresa, descricao_resumida, princ_clientes_1, princ_clientes_2, princ_clientes_3, tempo_mercado FROM tb_briefing WHERE email LIKE '". $_POST['user_email']. "%'");
  
  if($query->num_rows > 0){
   $userData = $query->fetch_assoc();
   $data['status'] = 'ok';
   $data['result'] = $userData;
  }else{
   $data['status'] = 'err';
   $data['result'] = '';
  }
  
  //returns data as JSON format
  echo json_encode($data);
  
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r ($userData);
  //print_r($data['status']);
  //echo "</pre>"; 
 }
?>
```

Se eu der um print_r e verificar no navegador, os valores estão lá (apesar de os acentos estarem vindo com uma interrogação no lugar). O problema é que funcionava, mas agora que estou acabando essa tela, não sei o que houve. Já revirei tudo, mas não preenche mais o input de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Uma opinião: var myObj = JSON.parse(data);if(myObj.status=='ok'){...}

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que está, o conteúdo enviado pelo servidor PHP, por padrão vai text/html, mas o jQuery precisa do content-type = json.

Você precisa setar o header como "application/json". Segue o código.

```
header("Content-Type","application/json");
```

PS: pode colocar uma linha antes do echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Eu coloquei, mas ainda não retorna nos inputs.